# Print PDF in new browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I have this two pieces of code that works today:

1. This one gets a blob file I retrieved from backend and open a 'print dialog' on current tab:

```
 var blob = new Blob([response.body], {type: 'application/pdf'});
 const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.style.display = 'none';
 iframe.src = blobUrl;
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

2. This one opens a new tab to download a file (which is returned as inline by the server):

```
 var form = document.createElement("form");
 form.target = "_blank";
 form.method = method;
 form.action = url;
 form.style.display = "none";
 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
```

Any idea how I can open the file in a new tab, but with the print dialog already opened?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const openNewWindow = () => {
    const newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.eval(newWindow.print());
};

openNewWindow();
```

This will open a new browser tab and then immediately open the print screen.

In your case, you'll need to be doing something like this:

```js
const openNewWindow = () => {
    const newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.eval(newWindow.print());
        
    var blob = new Blob([response.body],           {type:'application/pdf'});

    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const iframe = newWindow.document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = blobUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
};

    openNewWindow();
```

Hope that helps.